# unchecked checkbox with "Input::old()"

Tags: checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a checkbox in a view:

```
Form::checkbox('test', 'true', Input::old('test', true));
```

After unchecking the box, submitting the form and being redirected back:

```
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
```

The checkbox is still checked - presumably because `'test'` doesn't exist in `"Input::old"` so it is reverting back to the default value.

Any suggestions on how best to achieve this?

**Edit:**

I've come up with a somewhat hacky way of getting the results I want:

```
$isChecked = true; // The default state
// Check if the form has been returned "withInput"
if(Input::old())
{
    $isChecked = Input::old('test', false); // If the field has old data available use that, otherwise it is unchecked
}
echo Form::checkbox('test', 'true', $isChecked);
```

I'll write this into a function for reuse, but it seems a bit painful so any comments/suggestions would be great

**Edit 2**
Sorry if not clear - to clarify:

1. Form is loaded with checkbox checked
2. I uncheck the checkbox and submit the form
3. The form doesn't validate so I'm returned to the form
4. The checkbox has re-checked itself - I would expect it to be unchecked, as per the user submitted data

I assume this happens because if a checkbox isn't checked the element isn't included in the post data

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Turns out it was because I followed the instructions on how to post an unchecked checkbox, which said:

```
echo Form::hidden('name', 0);
echo Form::checkbox('name', 1);
```

The problem with this is that on form validation fail, if the checkbox was checked, Laravel will repopulate both 'hidden' and 'checkbox' fields with old value, so your hidden field will always be submitting 1 instead of 0. Simple solution is just write HTML for the hidden field instead of using the form helper:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="0">';
echo Form::checkbox('name', 1);
```

Comment: Followed what *instructions*?

Comment: This is mentioned in a comment here: https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-3/

Comment: Tnx, this fixed it for me. Using (old('active', $slide->active ?? 1) == 1) ? true : false, which basicly says: if  oldInput > Slide > 1  == 1, then true, otherwise false. "??" can be used as an shorthand for isset, to give an alternative value when something isn't available.

Answer (score 5):

This should is sufficient

```
echo Form::checkbox('test', 'true', Input::old('test', true));
```

If Input::old() doesn't exists, it will return true, your default.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but have you tested this?

If I uncheck the checkbox and submit, it is then checked when the form reloads - I beieve because Input::old('test') doesn't exist

Comment: @GuyIncognito This works because Laravel's form builder checks the session and if there is any old form data. `if (isset($this->session) && ! $this->oldInputIsEmpty() && is_null($this->old($name))) return false;` FormBuilder.php line 639 in laravel version 4.2.x-dev

Answer (score 2):

The checkbox and session mismatch was an error that has been corrected in Laravel 4. The following code should preserve the checkbox on redirect:

```
echo Form::checkbox('payment_method', 'credit');
```

For grouped checkboxes, use something like this:

```
echo Form::checkbox('payment_method[]', 'credit');
```

That should also work.

**Obviously you will want to replace payment_method and credit with your own attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit confusing for me too. But this is what I did.

In my controller,

```
Session::flash('test', Input::get('test') ? 'true' : 'false');
```

And in the view

```
<?php $test = Session::get('test'); ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" value="true" <?php echo is_null($test) ? 'checked' : ($test == 'true' ? 'checked' : ''); ?> />
```

So, pretty much using an additional session flash data to get around.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

`<?php $last_turnaround = (array) Input::old('turnaround'); ?>`

`{{ Form::checkbox( 'turnaround', 'normal', in_array('normal', $last_turnaround), array('id' => 'turnaround_normal', 'class' => 'turnaround')) }}`

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the same problem:

1) Remove the checkbox from validation. Logically, it makes no difference.

2) In my controller update function, I added an if statement that used isset to determine whether the value was sent or not (if not sent, it wasn't checked and therefore false).

```
if ($validation->passes())
{
    $xxx = $this->xxx->find($id);
    $xxx->update($input);
    if (!isset($input['checkbox_attribute'])) {
        $xxx->checkbox_attribute = false;
    }
    $xxx->save();
    return Redirect::to('xxx.show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem..

I fixed it like this

```
Form::checkbox('test', 'true', Input::old() ? Input::old('test', false) : true);
```

hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I end up with creating this helper function:

```
function is_checked(string $name, $value, $default) : string
{
    $current_defaults = Input::old() ? old($name, 0) : $default;
    return ($value == $current_defaults) ? 'checked' : '';
}

<input type="checkbox" name="is_acrive" value="1" 
       {{ is_checked('is_active', 1, $user->is_active) }}>
```

Multiple checkbox version:

```
function is_checked_multiple(string $name, $value, $defaults) : string
{
    $current_defaults = Input::old() ? old($name, []) : (array)$defaults;
    return in_array($value, $current_defaults) ? 'checked' : '';
}

@foreach ($plans as $plan)
    <input type="checkbox" name="plans[]" value="{{ $plan->id }}" 
           {{ is_checked_multiple('plans', $plan->id, $user->plans->pluck('id') }}>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm trying your first function and I get error `Class 'Input' not found `

Comment: `Input` is deprecated. use `Request` or `request()` instead.